# NHibernate throws NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException can not update during Fetch request

Tags: c#, exception, nhibernate, fetch

I am new to NHibernate and I am writing some code to get the total record count from a table using NHibernate fetch request, the code is like following:

```
 var query = request.RpcManager.Session.CreateCriteria(beanType);
 ......
 int totalRowCount = (int)query.UniqueResult<int>();
```

And the detail exception message is like following:

```
    NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was unhandled by user code
      HResult=-2146232832
      Message=could not update: [TestApi.DAO.AD_Window#125][SQL: UPDATE AD_WINDOW SET AD_CLIENT_ID = ?, AD_ORG_ID = ?, ISACTIVE = ?, CREATED = ?, CREATEDBY = ?, UPDATED = ?, UPDATEDBY = ?, NAME = ?, DESCRIPTION = ?, HELP = ?, WINDOWTYPE = ?, ISSOTRX = ?, ENTITYTYPE = ?, PROCESSING = ?, AD_IMAGE_ID = ?, AD_COLOR_ID = ?, ISDEFAULT = ?, WINHEIGHT = ?, WINWIDTH = ?, ISBETAFUNCTIONALITY = ? WHERE AD_WINDOW_ID = ?]
      Source=NHibernate
      SqlString=UPDATE AD_WINDOW SET AD_CLIENT_ID = ?, AD_ORG_ID = ?, ISACTIVE = ?, CREATED = ?, CREATEDBY = ?, UPDATED = ?, UPDATEDBY = ?, NAME = ?, DESCRIPTION = ?, HELP = ?, WINDOWTYPE = ?, ISSOTRX = ?, ENTITYTYPE = ?, PROCESSING = ?, AD_IMAGE_ID = ?, AD_COLOR_ID = ?, ISDEFAULT = ?, WINHEIGHT = ?, WINWIDTH = ?, ISBETAFUNCTIONALITY = ? WHERE AD_WINDOW_ID = ?
      StackTrace:
           at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
           at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
           at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
           at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
           at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
           at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
           at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
           at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
           at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.OnAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event)
           at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.AutoFlushIfRequired(ISet`1 querySpaces)
           at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)
           at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
           at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.UniqueResult[T]()
           ......
      InnerException: 
           Code=1407
           ErrorCode=-2146232008
           HResult=-2146232008
           Message=ORA-01407: cannot update ("COMPIERE"."AD_WINDOW"."CREATED") to NULL

           Source=System.Data.OracleClient
           StackTrace:
                at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
                at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
                at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor)
                at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
                at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)
                at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
           InnerException:
```

I am running a fetch request so I don't understand why the exception is about update, please give me some idea on how to fix this issue, thank you.

I tried to use code like :

```
request.RpcManager.Session.QueryOver<AD_Window>().RowCount();
```

But got the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a modified (or, at least, NH thinks it was modified, search Google for ghosts) entity in the first level (session) cache. Before doing a query, NH will try to flush everythng.
You probably can get away with it if you set the FlushMode on your ISession to Never, but the real problem remains.

Comment: As the fetch request is done by a generic request so it is inside a transaction. By taking out the transaction it solved the problem. Thanks.